# It is も and した right?

Tags: grammar, particle-も

彼女へのあげたプレゼントはご千円**もした**。The bolded part is も and した right?

Why is the particle も used there? 
While も rarely poses a problem in understanding a sentence, I often feel like I don't really understand why it is there :(

Comment: Off topic but... she's probably saying 彼ケチって5000円しか使わなかったよ! lol (sorry, just had to put that in)

Answer (score 7):

> 「5千円{せんえん}**も**した」

「も」 has far more meanings than people tend to think.

**This 「も」 expresses a surprise or deep impression**.

> "(It) cost me a whopping 5,000 yen."

It is saying that it was way more expensive than expected.

See definition #5 in [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%82-644757#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88).

> も［係助・接助・終助］［係助］
> ５ 驚{おどろ}き・感動{かんどう}の意{い}を表{あらわ}す。「この本{ほん}、三千円{さんぜんえん}**も**するんだって」

If you are **not** surprised by the price, you could just state the price as:

> 「～～は5千円した」 without a 「も」